# JMS Serializer SerializedName() not working

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, annotations, jmsserializerbundle

I have a **$character property** in my entity Foo.

The property is an entity itself (AppBundle\Entity\Character).

When I serialize Foo, I don't want to have the whole entity Character to be serialized: I need just the nickname of the Character.

I wrote this in AppBundle\Entity\Foo:

```
/**
 * 
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("character")
 */
public function getCharacterNickname()
{
    return $this->character->getNickname();
}
```

The "**virtual property**" annotation works.

But the "**serializedName**" doesn't, because the result is the following:

```
{
    "id": 18,
    "characterNickname": "Mr.Gilbert Norrel",
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": true,
    "baz": "baz"
}
```

("characterNickname" instead of just "character", as I asked in the annotation).

The properties "id", "foo", "bar" and "baz" have the annotation @**Serializer\Expose**(). The property "character" doesn't (because I want to serialize THAT property via the VirtualProperty)

What am I missing? 
Is it caused by the fact that I want to serialize the property with the name of an existing property?

Ty :)

Comment: Do you have `$character` property annotated with `@Serialize\Exclude()`?

Comment: might sound stupid but don't forget to clear the cache

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Nope (I tried both with $character property with that annotation, and withouth, and the answer is the same)

Comment: @SergeiKutanov Tried. Nothing changed :-/

Comment: Are you using a NamingStrategy other than default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/334

It seems that there's an error in the IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy file of the library.

Answer (score 0):

For people using symfony 3 with those jms versions :

```
//composer.json
  "jms/serializer-bundle": "2.4.4",
  "jms/serializer": "1.10.0",
  "jms/metadata": "1.7.0",
  "jms/parser-lib": "1.0.0"
```

I had the same problem, but there is a simple solution.

Let's first start with an example which will not work :

```
  /**
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("myFirstName")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"book:primitives"})
     */
    public function firstName()
    {
        return ($this->getAuthor() !== null) ? $this->getAuthor()->getFirstname() : '';
    }
```

The returned json with name the property with the nameof the function even if the **@SerializedName** is given.

To make jms take the **@SerializedName** in consideration , due to jms convention naming method , the virtual propery function name must be start with a **get** like getFirstName , getLastName, etc ...

```
/**
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("myFirstName")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"book:primitives"})
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return ($this->getAuthor() !== null) ? $this->getAuthor()->getFirstname() : '';
}
```

And then , your json here will contain the propery named **myFirstName**

good luck!